# Oracle - Where Not Exists

Tags: sql, oracle, not-exists

I am trying to return a list of people who are taking certain courses. These courses are identified by a field called CRNs.  If a person is not taking certain courses (CRNs), I need to return that list.  Using Where Not Exists in this query is currently returning no one, and there are hundreds of people in the dbase that do fall into this category.

Please take a look at the qry and let me know what is incorrect.

Thank you

```
    select  distinct 
    SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID
    
from

  SATURN.SPRIDEN
  
where not exists

        (select distinct
             
              SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID SID
              
              
        from 
         
          SATURN.SGBSTDN
          join SATURN.SFRSTCR
            on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PIDM
              and SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE
          join SATURN.SPRIDEN
            on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM
         join SATURN.SSBSECT
          on SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
            and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN
         join SATURN.SCBCRSE
          on SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE
            and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB

         
        where 

          SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID like '9%'
          and  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '202202'
          and SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
         and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE in ('RE', 'RW')
          and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE in ('A', 'E', 'O')
        and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE in ('H5A', 'H10')  --,'H5B', 'H10', 'HSL', 'HND', ,'HE3', 'H8')

        --Campus Course CRNs below
        and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN in ('30007',
        '30009',
        '30011',
        '30012',
        '30013',
        '30023',
        '30024',
        '30027',
        '30028',
        '30029',
        '30030',
        '30031',
        '30032',
        '30033',
        '30034',
        '30035',
        '30036',
        '30039',
        '30040',
        '30041',
        '30042',
        '30043',
        '30046',
        '30048',
        '30049',
        '30057',
        '30059',
        '30060',
        '30064',
        '30066',
        '30067',
        '30068',
        '30069',
        '30070',
        '30074',
        '30075',
        '30081',
        '30082',
        '30083',
        '30084',
        '30085',
        '30087',
        '30093',
        '30094',
        '30095',
        '30096',
        '30097',
        '30098',
        '30099',
        '30100',
        '30101',
        '30110',
        '30111',
        '30115',
        '30116',
        '30117',
        '30121',
        '30122',
        '30123',
        '30125',
        '30130',
        '30135',
        '30136',
        '30137',
        '30138',
        '30139',
        '30190',
        '30191',
        '30192',
        '30193',
        '30194',
        '30197',
        '30200',
        '30201',
        '30202',
        '30243',
        '30266',
        '30269',
        '30270',
        '30271',
        '30272',
        '30273',
        '30274',
        '30283',
        '30284',
        '30285',
        '30295',
        '30296',
        '30300',
        '30303',
        '30304',
        '30307',
        '30308',
        '30309',
        '30310',
        '30311',
        '30314',
        '30317',
        '30318',
        '30319',
        '30320',
        '30321',
        '30323',
        '30324',
        '30325',
        '30326',
        '30327',
        '30339',
        '30340',
        '30341',
        '30343',
        '30344',
        '30345',
        '30346',
        '30347',
        '30348',
        '30349',
        '30350',
        '30351',
        '30352',
        '30353',
        '30354',
        '30355',
        '30356',
        '30366',
        '30367',
        '30368',
        '30369',
        '30372',
        '30373',
        '30374')

        and SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM = (select max(scbcrse_eff_term) from saturn.scbcrse xppd
                where
                xppd.scbcrse_subj_code = scbcrse.scbcrse_subj_code
                and
                xppd.scbcrse_crse_numb = scbcrse.scbcrse_crse_numb and xppd.scbcrse_eff_term <= ssbsect_term_code)
                

)
```

Comment: Try ``SATURN.SPRIDEN_ID NOT IN`` instead of ``NOT EXISTS``.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `WHERE <field> NOT IN (SELECT <field> FROM <table>)` instead of where not exists.

```
select  distinct 
    SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID    
from
  SATURN.SPRIDEN  
where SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID not in
        (select distinct             
              SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID SID             
        from          
          SATURN.SGBSTDN
          join SATURN.SFRSTCR
            on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PIDM
              and SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE
          join SATURN.SPRIDEN
            on SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM
         join SATURN.SSBSECT
          on SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
            and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN
         join SATURN.SCBCRSE
          on SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE
            and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB        
        where 
          SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID like '9%'
          and  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '202202'
          and SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND is null
         and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE in ('RE', 'RW')
          and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE in ('A', 'E', 'O')
        and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE in ('H5A', 'H10')  --,'H5B', 'H10', 'HSL', 'HND', ,'HE3', 'H8')
        --Campus Course CRNs below
        and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN in ('30007',
        '30009',        '30011',        '30012',        '30013',        '30023',        '30024',        '30027',
        '30028',        '30029',        '30030',        '30031',        '30032',        '30033',        '30034',
        '30035',        '30036',        '30039',        '30040',        '30041',        '30042',        '30043',
        '30046',        '30048',        '30049',        '30057',        '30059',        '30060',        '30064',
        '30066',        '30067',        '30068',        '30069',        '30070',        '30074',        '30075',
        '30081',        '30082',        '30083',        '30084',        '30085',        '30087',        '30093',
        '30094',        '30095',        '30096',        '30097',        '30098',        '30099',        '30100',
        '30101',        '30110',        '30111',        '30115',        '30116',        '30117',        '30121',
        '30122',        '30123',        '30125',        '30130',        '30135',        '30136',        '30137',
        '30138',        '30139',        '30190',        '30191',        '30192',        '30193',        '30194',
        '30197',        '30200',        '30201',        '30202',        '30243',        '30266',        '30269',
        '30270',        '30271',        '30272',        '30273',        '30274',        '30283',        '30284',
        '30285',        '30295',        '30296',        '30300',        '30303',        '30304',        '30307',
        '30308',        '30309',        '30310',        '30311',        '30314',        '30317',        '30318',
        '30319',        '30320',        '30321',        '30323',        '30324',        '30325',        '30326',
        '30327',        '30339',        '30340',        '30341',        '30343',        '30344',        '30345',
        '30346',        '30347',        '30348',        '30349',        '30350',        '30351',        '30352',
        '30353',        '30354',        '30355',        '30356',        '30366',        '30367',        '30368',
        '30369',        '30372',        '30373',        '30374')
        and SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM = (select max(scbcrse_eff_term) from saturn.scbcrse xppd
                where
                xppd.scbcrse_subj_code = scbcrse.scbcrse_subj_code
                and
                xppd.scbcrse_crse_numb = scbcrse.scbcrse_crse_numb and xppd.scbcrse_eff_term <= ssbsect_term_code))
```

Comment: Thank you, Pepe.  This suggestion does return results as I have tried a variation of Not In previously.  But it is not yielding the correct results.  These CRNs are course numbers, some are for online courses, some are for on-campus courses.  I am trying to determine which student are only taking online courses, they can be taking multiple courses and possibly one of each.  I need to know which students only have online courses.  Suggestions?

Comment: How do we know that a course is online with the given fields? Or your CRN codes some particularity for online courses?

Comment: You don't, the list of CRNs that are in the the qry are all on-campus courses only.  So, I was creating the query using the Not Exists method to show all records that do not exist with the given CRNs above.  That should return a list where people are only taking online, correct?

Comment: Yes it should be `SFRSTCR_CRN NOT IN (<list>)` you could deconstruct your query in it's component parts and test everything separately to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Without a deep understanding of the data model, it is difficult to give a solid answer to the question. The following answer assumes that this query will return a list of all students and courses in the scope of interest, including students who are taking only online courses, only campus courses, and both types of courses:

```
SELECT 
       SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID  AS S_ID
      ,SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN AS COURSE_NBR
  FROM 
       SATURN.SGBSTDN
       JOIN SATURN.SFRSTCR
          ON SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PIDM
         AND SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE
             JOIN SATURN.SSBSECT
               ON SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
              AND SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN
                  JOIN SATURN.SCBCRSE
                    ON SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE
                   AND SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB
        JOIN SATURN.SPRIDEN
          ON SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM
 WHERE
        SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID LIKE '9%'
   AND  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '202202'
   AND  SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND IS NULL
   AND  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE IN ('RE', 'RW')
   AND  SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE IN ('A', 'E', 'O')
   AND  SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE IN ('H5A', 'H10')
   AND  SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM = (
                                     SELECT MAX(XPPD.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM)
                                       FROM SATURN.SCBCRSE XPPD
                                      WHERE XPPD.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE
                                        AND XPPD.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB
                                        AND XPPD.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM <= SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
                                   )
```

If that assumption is incorrect, the rest of this answer is nonsense.

From reading the OP's comments, it seems that the goal is to get a list of students who are only taking online courses. (Not at all clear to me in the original post.) That means, given all the students and courses in scope, exclude any that have at least one campus course in their schedule.

So, create a CTE of all students in scope, then look through that CTE and exclude any IDs that correspond to a student taking a Campus course.

```
WITH STUDENT_COURSE AS (
SELECT 
       SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID  AS S_ID
      ,SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN AS COURSE_NBR
  FROM 
       SATURN.SGBSTDN
       JOIN SATURN.SFRSTCR
          ON SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PIDM
         AND SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE
             JOIN SATURN.SSBSECT
               ON SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
              AND SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN
                  JOIN SATURN.SCBCRSE
                    ON SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE
                   AND SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB
        JOIN SATURN.SPRIDEN
          ON SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM = SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM
 WHERE
        SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID LIKE '9%'
   AND  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = '202202'
   AND  SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND IS NULL
   AND  SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE IN ('RE', 'RW')
   AND  SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE IN ('A', 'E', 'O')
   AND  SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE IN ('H5A', 'H10')
   AND  SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM = (
                                     SELECT MAX(XPPD.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM)
                                       FROM SATURN.SCBCRSE XPPD
                                      WHERE XPPD.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE
                                        AND XPPD.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB = SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB
                                        AND XPPD.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM <= SSBSECT_TERM_CODE
                                   )
)
  SELECT
          SC1.S_ID
    FROM
          STUDENT_COURSE SC1
   WHERE
          SC1.S_ID NOT IN ( SELECT SC2.S_ID
                              FROM STUDENT_COURSE SC2
                             WHERE SC2.COURSE_NBR IN
         --Campus Course CRNs below
         (
           '30007', '30009', '30011', '30012', '30013', '30023', '30024'
          ,'30027', '30028', '30029', '30030', '30031', '30032', '30033'
          ,'30034', '30035', '30036', '30039', '30040', '30041', '30042'
          ,'30043', '30046', '30048', '30049', '30057', '30059', '30060'
          ,'30064', '30066', '30067', '30068', '30069', '30070', '30074'
          ,'30075', '30081', '30082', '30083', '30084', '30085', '30087'
          ,'30093', '30094', '30095', '30096', '30097', '30098', '30099'
          ,'30100', '30101', '30110', '30111', '30115', '30116', '30117'
          ,'30121', '30122', '30123', '30125', '30130', '30135', '30136'
          ,'30137', '30138', '30139', '30190', '30191', '30192', '30193'
          ,'30194', '30197', '30200', '30201', '30202', '30243', '30266'
          ,'30269', '30270', '30271', '30272', '30273', '30274', '30283'
          ,'30284', '30285', '30295', '30296', '30300', '30303', '30304'
          ,'30307', '30308', '30309', '30310', '30311', '30314', '30317'
          ,'30318', '30319', '30320', '30321', '30323', '30324', '30325'
          ,'30326', '30327', '30339', '30340', '30341', '30343', '30344'
          ,'30345', '30346', '30347', '30348', '30349', '30350', '30351'
          ,'30352', '30353', '30354', '30355', '30356', '30366', '30367'
          ,'30368', '30369', '30372', '30373', '30374'
         )
GROUP BY
         SC1.S_ID
;
```

The above answer is untested and may contain trivial errors, however, the logic should be sound. There may be (and probably is) a much better way to do this, but without understanding meaning of the additional joins, optimization is difficult.

Comment: Posted with some trepidation. I'll try to watch for comments and update the answer if needed.